# Missing C++ Windows Runtime Component template

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-runtime

I'm trying to follow [Consuming a C++ library project from a Windows Phone Store app](http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisbarker/2014/10/08/consuming-a-c-library-project-from-a-windows-phone-store-app/). At the first step, the article instructs us:

> So, the first step is going to be to create the C++ WinRT component. You can do this by adding a new project to the solution and selecting the appropriate project type as demonstrated in Figure 2. For the purposes of this example, the project type will be “Windows Runtime Component (Windows Phone) – Visual C++” (highlighted in green) as the application calling it is a Windows Phone Store app.

The problem I am having is I don't have the C++ Windows Runtime Component template installed. And its not available online, either:

[image]

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, and I have the Windows Phone SDK installed along with the Windows Phone 8.0 kit. The article does not detail a Visual Studio version, but according to the [Microsoft Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) we need Visual Studio 2012 and above for these apps.

Where, exactly, does one find the C++ Windows Runtime Component template?

---

The underlying problem I am trying to solve is the missing declaration for `HANDLE`, `VOID`, etc. It appears they are not included with `<windows.h>`. So I'm trying to duplicate a simple "Hello World" project to see what Microsoft includes in their sample projects.

```
cl.exe /nologo /W4 /D_MBCS /Zi /TP /EHsc /MD /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMI
LY_PHONE_APP /AI"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata"
 /c test.cpp
test.cpp
...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\minwinbase.h(46) : error C214
6: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nLength'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\minwinbase.h(46) : error C443
0: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um\minwinbase.h(47) : error C214
6: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'lpSecurityDescriptor'
...
```

But please don't focus on this problem; focus on the missing Visual Studio templates so I can fix future problems, too.

Comment: "I have Visual Studio Ultimate" Which version? 2012,13,15?

Comment: @VolkerK - its VS2012. The details have been added to the question.